# Using an authentication provider to keep a user permanently logged in eventually causes session problems

Tags: authentication-authorization, sessions

Because I got fed up of having to log in to my local development sites every however long, I tried making a simple custom module that just has an Authentication Provider service that always returns user 1, like this:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function applies(Request $request) {
    return TRUE;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function authenticate(Request $request) {
    return $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('user')->load(1);
  }
```

The idea being that with this module enabled, every page load considers the authenticated user to be user 1. In theory, I'd be logged in for ever!

However, after a few weeks of this working fine, all my form submissions broke! Every form submission fails with:

> The form has become outdated. Press the back button, copy any unsaved work in the form, and then reload the page

This turns out to be because CsrfTokenGenerator::validate() fails. Specifically, the $seed in this bit is just NULL:

```
  public function validate($token, $value = '') {
    $seed = $this->sessionMetadata->getCsrfTokenSeed();
    if (empty($seed)) {
      return FALSE;
    }
```

I presume it's because the session has expired in some way? The time this has taken to stop working is roughly the amount of time it would have taken the site to log me out automatically.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I know this is not a solution to your problem specifically, but maybe this could work as an alternative for you https://www.drupal.org/project/persistent_login

Answer (score 0):

> I presume it's because the session has expired in some way?

First you need to understand how this happens.

> #### Configuring Garbage Collection
>
> When a session opens, PHP will call the `gc` handler randomly
> according to the probability set by `session.gc_probability` /
> `session.gc_divisor`. For example if these were set to 5/100
> respectively, it would mean a probability of 5%. Similarly, 3/4 would
> mean a 3 in 4 chance of being called, i.e. 75%.
>
> If the garbage collection handler is invoked, PHP will pass the value
> stored in the **php.ini** directive `session.gc_maxlifetime`. The
> meaning in this context is that any stored session that was saved more
> than `gc_maxlifetime` ago should be deleted. This allows one to expire
> records based on idle time.
>
> However, some operating systems (e.g. Debian) do their own session
> handling and set the `session.gc_probability` variable to 0 to stop
> PHP doing garbage collection. That's why Symfony now overwrites this
> value to 1.
>
> If you wish to use the original value set in your **php.ini**, add the
> following configuration:
>
> ```
> # config/packages/framework.yaml
> framework:
>     session:
>         gc_probability: null
> ```
>
> <sub>Source: [Symphony's official docs on Configuring Sessions and Save Handlers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html)</sub>

In Drupal 8 & 9 you can see these gc settings in [default.services.yml](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/9.2.x/sites/default/default.services.yml#L2)

#### Possible Solutions on how to stay logged in longer.

In /sites/default/**settings.php** uncomment

```
 if (file_exists($app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php')) {
   include $app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php';
 }
```

then copy **/sites/example.settings.local.php** and rename to **/sites/default/settings.local.php**

Now you can use **/sites/development.services.yml** to override those settings, for example

(I used these numbers for testing so it logs me out after 2 seconds):

```
parameters:
  session.storage.options:
    gc_probability: 1
    gc_divisor: 1
    gc_maxlifetime: 2
    cookie_lifetime: 2
```

I tried setting `gc_probability` to `0` or `null`, which should stop it, but the `gc()` function still fired. Perhaps it's reading the value from php.ini

So alternatively you could set the `gc_maxlifetime` and `cookie_lifetime` to not expire decades from now. See [set a cookie to never expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290424/set-a-cookie-to-never-expire).